# Having Trouble Mapping Tags using acts_as_taggable gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm trying to set up tags for a tools list. I'm using the acts_as_taggable gem. I'm able to get the tags to display, but not link them to a specific tag. Following railscast I

```
<% @tools.each_slice(3) do |muc| %>
<% muc.each do |tool| %>
Tags: <%= tool.tag.map { |t| link_to t, tag_path(t) }.join(', ') %>
```

but i'm getting an error, 'undefined method `map' for "tool":String'

suggestions? thanks!

Comment: can you show us what the `muc` object is and how you set it?

Comment: Oh sorry, left that out by accident. Above the Muc I have another loop to split it to three sections. <% @tools.each_slice(3) do |muc| %>

Comment: What does tool.tag return? Sounds like it's returning a String. I believe the correct method to use is `tags`, plural? Is `tag` a method you wrote?